# Where Clause in Query to match Phonenumber

Tags: apex, query, formatting, locale, number

How can I match for phonenumber in my whereclause?

My query:

SELECT id, Membership_number__c, Phone, Email FROM Contact WHERE Phone = :phoneNumberString

Above mathces fine on these phonenumber values:
+4550516254

004550516254

50516254

But not this one:

4550516254

Any ideas?
Just to clarify, the query doesn't return the same record for the three "matching" cases, but it can actually return a record. The latter one, can't.

Comment: I don't suppose you've tried `FIND {+4550516254} IN PHONE FIELDS RETURNING Lead(Id, Membership_Number__c, Phone, Email)`?

Comment: Now I'm quite sure that this is actually not an issue with the query.
It seems like if I include the plussign, when I call the method through Execute Anonomously it works. But problenm occurs when the URL parameter which I use as input in my Search Query has a plussign in it.
I know that the plussign should actually be: %2B when it's in the URL, is there somehow i can treat it as a plussign or do I need to modify the URL